# Tizen Studio "repository configutation cannot be downloaded"

Tags: tizen

I'm trying to install the Samsung TV extension packages in Tizen Package Manager. When I go to the "Extension SDK" page I should see the tools to download but nothing is there. When I check in settings I see that the package repo url isn't working:

http://download.tizen.org/sdk/tizenstudio

"The repository configutation cannot be downloaded"

What can I do? I tried installing the package manually but  I just get "Installation failed" :S

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can download tv extension.

1. I downloaded TizenStudio 4.5.1 version from https://developer.tizen.org/
2. I used https://download.tizen.org/sdk/tizenstudio URL on the package-manger instead of http://download.tizen.org/sdk/tizenstudio
3. I installed tv extension

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the http(s) issue. By default it comes as http :S